# Is it safe to use 'space blankets' over loose fill insulation in an attic?

Tags: insulation, attic, moisture

My townhouse has a small attic area over a bedroom (and another inaccessible space over another room). The attic space is on the south side of the building and there is a lot of heat gain in the summer. The bedroom stays overly warm far in to the night due to heat in the attic.

The attic space appears to have adequate loose-fill insulation and enough ventilation, but not a powered vent. The space is continuous with the adjacent unit (no firewall between unit attics - different issue). I don't want to put a powered roof vent here, although I am planning to have one installed in the inaccessible space over the other bedroom.

The ceiling of this bedroom with the attic over it gets noticably warm in the summer, so I took 3 'space blankets' - silvery mylar sheets about 4x8 foot - and spread them loosely over the insulation. I am trying to reflect heat away, not improve the R value for winter at this point. Could this cause any problems like trapped moisture or condensation in winter? The ceiling does feel much less warm after doing this, so it seems like a really easy fix.

Comment: AFIK  water vapor moves through the ceiling into the attic. It would seem possible that a vapor impermeable membrane over the loose insulation could trap moisture.

Comment: @JimStewart I suppose I should go look on a particularly cold morning and see if there is condensation.

Comment: See https://buildingscience.com/users/jlstiburek Joe Lstiburek is a specialist in moisture control. Check out some of his videos.  He has said that efforts to achieve maximum insulation have sometimes led to moisture rentention that led to serious damage. This subject seems tricky and complicated.